# ReviseItinerary does not add activity to the routingslip

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I need to add an activity on the fly inside another activity. I tried

```
context.ReviseItinerary(i => i.AddActivity(...)).
```

It doesn't seems to do anything. Am I missing something?

I use the latest client of MassTransit Nuget package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your activity, as a return from the `Execute` method, the return value of the `ReviseItinerary` call should be returned.

```
public async Task<ExecutionResult> Execute(ExecuteContext<Arguments> context)
{
    return context.ReviseItinerary(x => ...);
}
```

Comment: Right now I use return context.Completed(new IngestLog { TrackingNumber = context.TrackingNumber }). How do I continue to do that for Compensate() to work correctly?

Comment: There is an overload that allows you to specify the log, works the same as Completed. https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit/Courier/ExecuteContext.cs#L111